# want to know if SQL is correct

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this code correct?

Are the following points right?

- The primary key fields.
- The varchar(500) to store a quotation (i.g., famous words by certain people such as philosophers or politicians).
- The external keys.

```
CREATE TABLE quote (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    quote VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE topic (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    topic VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    parentTopic INT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (parentTopic) REFERENCES topic(id)
);
CREATE TABLE quoteTopics (
    quote INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    topic INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (quote, topic),
    FOREIGN KEY ( quote ) REFERENCES quote(id),
    FOREIGN KEY ( topic ) REFERENCES topic(id)
);
```

Comment: Maybe try to eloborate on the term "correct" in this specific case.

Comment: what happened when you tried it ?

Comment: Key syntax is different between the sql servers. It seems mysql, because other servers don't have "auto_increment" keyword. On mysql, it seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I would suggest is using `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `VARCHAR(500)` unless there's a valid reason to only support 500 characters.  That way you won't run out of storage as often and you can still use text functions like MID, LIKE, etc.

Comment: Apparently VARCHAR(MAX) doesn't work in MySQL. Should I use VARCHAR(65535) instead?

Comment: @user1314836 Sorry - I was assuming MSSQL.  500 just seemed a bit small for "free text".  You are correct - varchar only uses as much space as it needs.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be doing this in MySQL.

I notice that your topics have a hierarchical structure.  In MySQL, it is quite challenging to manage such hierarchies, and yet, one often does.  Assuming that the topics do not change very often, I would recommend including the "topic" path as a column.  For instance, if the topics are:

```
topic1 --> topic11 --> topic111
```

Then the path would be something like "topic1/topic11/topic111".  Note that this is denormalized, with the same data (topics) repeated in different rows.  It works if the topics and the hierarchies are not really updated (inserts are ok).

Some additional suggestions.  When a column references an id column, append `Id` onto the name.  So:  `ParentTopicId` instead of `ParentTopic`; `QuoteId` instead of `Quote` and `TopicId` instead of `Topic`.  This is especially important for your data.  When two columns have the same name in different tables, they should be at least sort of the same thing.  However, `Topic` is the text form of the topic in one table, but the id of the topic in another.

I would be inclined to include a primary key in `QuoteTopic` called `QuoteTopicId`.  This would be useful, for instance, if this table were being referenced by another table.

And, I suspect that your data structure is missing the whole author dimension.  A quote is interesting because of who said it.

Finally, in most tables, I like to include the columns `CreatedBy` and `CreatedAt` as autofilled columns.  In MySQL `CreatedAt` is easily enough added using a timestamp.  Unfortunately, `CreatedBy` would require a trigger, which is overkill.

Comment: It's MySQL, sorry for not mentioning that. I don't see why managing a hierarchy like the one I propose I challenging. I will create a page showing all the quotes with a "top" topic (this is, a topic with no parent topic) and showing all the subtopics whose father is that one). Nothing else, I believe this is easy to do with PHP MySQL. All the other suggestions are great. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1314836 . . . Just wait until you want to list all topics beneath a particular topic.  Or, you want to find all topics at depth 4.    Or determine if there are cycles in your topic hierarchy.  MySQL doesn't support recursive CTEs, so such queries are more difficult than they need to be.